eventListener click/pointerdown/touchstart doesn't work in mobile
I'm working on responsive navbar, and this is my codes
HTML:
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-header-button">Book a Meeting</a>
</div>

CSS :


.toggle-navbar {
    display: none;
    width: 1.5rem;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .toggle-navbar{
        display: block;
    }
}

.toggle-navbar i {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #eb0000;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 3rem;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.5rem;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 30;
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    transition: height 300ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) ease-in-out;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.open {
    display: block;
    height: 12rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}


.dropdown-menu a {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eb0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}
.dropdown-menu a:hover {
    color: #701414;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}



JS:
window.onload = function () {
const toggleNavbar = document.querySelector(".toggle-navbar");
const toggleNavbarIcon = document.querySelector(".toggle-navbar i");
const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");

const toggleMenu = function () {
    dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("open");
    const isOpen = dropdownMenu.classList.contains("open");
    toggleNavbarIcon.classList = isOpen ? "fa-solid fa-xmark" : "fa-solid fa-bars";
};

toggleNavbar.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
// toggleNavbar.addEventListener("touchstart", toggleMenu);
// toggleNavbar.addEventListener("pointerdown", toggleMenu);};

so actually this codes actually work pretty fine in PC browser, even tho i am using dimension responsive and simulating touchscreen, except using eventListener("touchstart"), it needs to long press the button, then i decide to use the pointerdown. but when it run on mobile, at first it works fine using click or pointerdown, but when i was working on another section and tried to run it again the navbar button doesn't work anymore after page refresh, i set it back to click and it did work but again after refreshing page it doesn't work, then i revert it back to pointerdown and thing goes repeatly.
how do i fix this?
